# Is it acceptable to use a hand reamer on an X-Y CNC machined hole?

Tags: bearings, cnc, holes

I would like to seat some bearings into a piece of aluminum, and I only have access to a small CNC machine.  The CNC has ball screws and is calibrated to maybe 50um error in the actual travel on x and y axes.  I assume this hole is not as circular or straight as what could be produced on a lathe or boring machine.   I can’t say much about the bearings as I haven’t selected them yet - they will be angular contact and  the application is for a small desktop robotic arm. I expect to pay about $10-15 for each bearing and would ideally like to get my money’s worth by “doing it as right as possible”.

The outer diameter of the bearing might be on the order of 24mm.   I am confident that I can cut a circular hole using the CNC and get some sort of a “press fit”, but I have the understanding that when people seat bearings they usually use a boring machine, lathe, and/or a reamer tool.  Is using the small CNC machine to create an undersized hole and then hand-reaming this a feasible approach?

My understanding is that reamers will “follow” an existing hole and that this is why hand reaming (which lacks the rigidity of a machine) could work.

Finally, one of the framers I have is Morse taper so not sure if people hand ream with those or if it’s pretty much only used on a mill or lathe.

Comment: If it produces acceptable results, it is acceptable. Specs for parts these days are toleranced to reflect needs of part rather than recipes on how to make a part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been told that a reamer will follow a hole, but now that you bring up manual reaming I don't think this applies to hand reamers. Hand reamers are tapered to reduce cutting force and assist entering the hole free-hand. But this taper means it can start off-angle, cuts along the length, and cut off angle.

Machine reamers follow the hole by having a very long shaft that can bend and also by only cutting at the tip. But the edges behind the tip act to improve the surface finish and hug the sides of the hole to keep things straight. That means machine reamers follow the hole, but they also sort of don't.  For example, for a really deep hole you can pre-drill the entire depth, and then bore only an inch down (rather than the entire depth) as a guide for the reamer. The reason is so the reamer follows the bored at the top of the hole and once it has reamed deep enough the now reamed sides of the bored starter hold the reamer in alignment so it remains straight for the remainder of the depth.

It's not going to come out straight because you aren't going to be able to start it straight and keep it straight with a hand reamer.

Boring ensures a hole is on-center, round, and straight, and covers a variety of sizes but does not guarantee that they are untapered and can be a real chore to dial in a particular size. Reamers ensure holes are round and untapered, and can do so at greater depths than boring, and are also faster to get something to-size (because you don't need to dial in the size...you just grab the size you need). Drilling just makes openings that are neither round, on-center, untapered, straight or to size but it does so very quickly. Drilling also has the worst finish.

Answer (score 1):

> can’t say much about the bearings as I haven’t selected them yet

Well that's the problem right there.  You need to figure out what precision level bearing you need first, and then decide if you can manufacture something to that spec. i.e. you need to consider things like the speed, load, life, reliability, etc. For some bearings, a hand reamed hole might be overkill, for others it might be totally unacceptable.

> I expect to pay about $10-15 for each bearing

Without knowing anything else about the bearing but the cost, my initial reaction is that a hand reamed hole is probably fine.  For $10 bearings I've used a drill press (without reaming) and gotten acceptable results.

If your application requires \$2000 bearings, then you need to pay very close attention to details.  For \$10 maybe not so much.